# grails deleted object would be re-saved by cascade error

Tags: hibernate, grails-orm, grails

I have the project as set-up below. I am trying to delete a project, and I get the following:

```
2010-09-29 11:45:22,902 [http-8080-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associatio
ns): [Project#204]
org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [Project#204]
        at ProjectController$_closure6.doCall(ProjectController:50)
        at ProjectController$_closure6.doCall(ProjectController)
        at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.JSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(JSecurityFilter.java:382)
        at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:180)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Is there any way to get hibernate to tell me which object has the reference back to the Project object that would be re-saved. What is wrong with my project set up that is causing this circular exception?

```
public class Project implements Comparable
{  
    static belongsTo = [employee:Employee]

    static hasMany = [roles:Role]
    static constraints = {

    }
    static mapping = {
          description type:"text"
          roles lazy:false, cascade:"all,delete-orphan"
          client lazy:false, cascade:"all,delete-orphan"
          employer lazy:false, cascade:"all,delete-orphan"
    }
}


class Employee implements Comparable
{
    static hasMany = [employeeDesiredSkills:EmployeeDesiredSkill,
                      employeeDesiredTools:EmployeeDesiredTool,
                      employeeAreasOfExpertise:EmployeeAreaOfExpertise,
                      projects:Project,
                      education:Education]


    static mapping = {
           employeeDesiredSkills cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
           employeeDesiredTools cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
           education cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
           projects cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
    }
}

public class Role implements Comparable
{

    static belongsTo = [project:Project]
    static hasMany = [roleSkills:RoleSkill,roleTools:RoleTool]

    static mapping = {
        duties type:"text"
        roleSkills cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
        roleTools cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
        locationType cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false

    }

    static contraints = {
        endDate(nullable: true)
        roleSkills(nullable: true)
        roleTools(nullable: true)
    }
}

class Employer implements Comparable
{
   static mapping = {
       type lazy:false, cascade:"all,delete-orphan"
   }
}

class RoleTool implements Comparable    
{


  static belongsTo = [role:Role, tool:Tool]//not sure this makes sense, but have to leave it or DB breaks
  Tool tool = new Tool(name:"")
    static mapping = {
      tool cascade:"save-update", lazy:false

    }


class RoleSkill implements Comparable   
{

  static belongsTo = [role:Role, skill:Skill]//not sure this makes sense, but have to leave it or DB breaks
    Skill skill = new Skill(name:"")
    static mapping = {
       skill cascade:"save-update", lazy:false

    }
}

class Skill implements Comparable
{
    static hasMany = [roleSkills:RoleSkill, employeeDesiredSkills:EmployeeDesiredSkill]

    static mapping = {
        roleSkills cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
        employeeDesiredSkills cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false

    }

}

class Tool implements Comparable
{

    static hasMany = [roleTools:RoleTool, employeeDesiredTools:EmployeeDesiredTool]

    static mapping = {
        roleTools cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
        employeeDesiredTools cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Infact, the way you have done the mapping 
`projects cascade:"all,delete-orphan"`
in the Employee class.

You'll just need to do:

```
def employee = project.employee; 
employee.removeFromProjects(project);
```

And the project will be deleted as well.
For more details, refer to [GORM Gotchas By Peter Ledbrook](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/).
Its a 3 part series and explains many similar situations

Comment: I finally got it working. It is not infact that simple. I think that there is a grails bug if the projects are stored in SortedSet, then it has a hard time doing that remove. I had to make a copy of the the projects, remove the one I wanted to delete, then add them back to employee to get this to work

Answer (score 6):

I know it is late but someone may like to find this here: 
What happens is that Hibernate uses 'dirtyChecking', as explained in [GORM Gotchas By Peter Ledbrook](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/).

To make things short: 
Hibernate, and so Grails will want to `save()` the `employee` object at the end of the Hibernate session (in your case at the `.delete(flush:true)` call) because it detects that the object has been modified (a `project` has been suppressed). And the `employee` must have kept a link toward the `project`, causing Hibernate to feel you will `delete()` the `project` to `save()` it back again.

To workaround this:

```
 def employee = project.employee; 
 employee.discard(); 
 project.delete(flush:true);
```

This tell Hibernate not to `save()` the `employee`without you asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have cascade for delete setup, like you do,  you need to remove the object-to-delete from its parent before deleting it.  From your stacktrace in ProcectController around line 50.

Comment: when you say "object to delete from its parent" does that mean that for this examle I need to remove Project from employee, or do I explicitly have to go down the tree removing all objects taht are about to be deleted from their parents?

Comment: Here is how I was doing the remove from ProjectController: def employee = project.employee;
         employee.removeFromProjects(project);
            project.delete(flush:true)

Answer (score 0):

It because at the end of transaction, grails and hibernate will be auto save Parent object, and it detected that a Child deleted so it will not allow delete the Object.
So we need:

```
child.parent.discard()
child.delete()
```

You can refer [here](https://pritomkumar.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-deleted-object-would-be-re-saved.html).
It resolve my issue.